# How to bake a curve animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves, baking

I'm trying to animate a curve with hooks.

[image: the curve (just an example)]

And I want to upload the curve to Sketchfab but it doesn't supports curves it gives errors on the model, so I want to bake the animation to a mesh madded by the curve with Bevel.
[image]